# Disabling norms causes empty result

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my mapping :

```
...
'mappings' : {
    'listing' : {
        'properties' : {
            'name' : {
                'type' : 'string',
                'boost' : 10,
                'index' : 'analyzed',
                'analyzer' : 'search_analyzer',
        //      'norms' : {'enabled' : false}
            },
...
```

When I uncomment `norms` and then reindex, I don't get any error on reindexing but all queries return empty (`0 hits`)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The norms.enabled setting must have the same setting for fields of the same name in the same index.